# Rails dynamic subpath route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

This seems like it should be easy to do, but I'm not sure how offhand.

I have State and Statute models, and currently use paths like these:

```
/california/statutes/robbery
/newyork/statutes/burglary
```

using this route:

```
match '/:state_id/statutes/:id' => 'statutes#show', :as => :state_statute, :id => /[^\/]+/
```

But the thing is, in California, statutes are called *codes*. And in NY, they're *laws*.

My question is, how could I automatically support these more meaningful paths:

```
/california/codes/robbery
/newyork/laws/burglary
```

I have this information stored in the model, which can be used; Statute.meta_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
match '/:state_id/:law/:id' => 'statutes#show', :as => :state_statute, :id => /[^\/]+/, :law => Regexp.new(Statute.meta_name.join("|"))
```

The problem with this is that both these urls would work:

```
/california/laws/robbery
/newyork/laws/burglary
```

Which is generally bad for SEO. You could fix that by adding a before filter like:

```
before_filter :validate_law_title

def validate_law_title
    unless <condition to check if the title used is correct, ie, codes for cali, laws for NY>
        redirect_to <correctly generated url>, :status=>:moved_permanently
    end
end
```

-- Edit --

To make the generation of routes easier, use a route like:

```
match '/:state_id/:law/:id' => 'statutes#show', :as => "_state_statute", :id => /[^\/]+/, :law => Regexp.new(Statute.meta_name.join("|"))
```

And in application_controller, or preferably a lib file, you could add:

```
# law is the law/rule, etc object
def state_statute_path(law, options={})
    options.merge!(:law => <figure out the label to use from the law object>)
    _state_statute_path(options)
end
```

Comment: That's interesting. So, to produce the path in the app, I'd specify the :law parameter. And then the regex ensures that only valid meta_names are acceptable in the other direction?

Comment: @Dogweather, yes. Ive also updated the answer with an easier way for url generation.

Comment: That's a nice trick - using a private name for the built-in path generator. You're right to be concerned about the SEO / duplicate data problem. I generally also include the canonical meta tag in complex sites like these.